# Edit form this.form.dirty is always true how to handle in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a edit form in my angular 6 project ngOnInit() i am calling a API and populating the form with the Data I get. But I don't want the form to be dirty as I have not change the data manually yet. Angular makes "form.dirty" to "true" as soon as the form value changes.

I want to check if the form values are changed by user after I load the form with data. Is that possible.

Comment: Create your form after you have fetched the data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this.formName.markAsPristine();

Comment: Working Now Thanks.  this.formName.form.markAsPristine();